Maximizing the Magnitude of a Complex Linear Combination with Binary Selection Variables
Given fixed $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{C} ^{1\times N}$, $N$, and $L$ ($N>L$), we have the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}\underset{\boldsymbol{\alpha },\bar{\mathbf{B}}}{\max}&\,\,|\mathbf{x}^H\bar{\mathbf{B}}\boldsymbol{\alpha }|
\\
\mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.&\boldsymbol{\alpha }=[e^{j\alpha _1},e^{j\alpha _2},\cdots ,e^{j\alpha _L}]^T,\alpha _l\in \left[ 0,2\pi \right),
\\
&\bar{\mathbf{B}}=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{b}_{1}^{T}\\
 \mathbf{b}_{2}^{T}\\
 …\\
 \mathbf{b}_{N}^{T}\\
\end{array} \right] ,\mathbf{b}_n\,\,=\,\,[b_n[1],\cdots ,b_n[L]]^T,
\\
&b_n[l]\in \{0,1\},\sum\nolimits_{l=1}^L{b_n}[l]=1.
\end{align}
If $\bar{\mathbf{B}}$ is fixed, the optimal solution of $\boldsymbol{\alpha }$ is easy to obtain. We define $\boldsymbol{\beta }^H=\mathbf{x}^{H}\bar{\mathbf{B}}\in \mathbb{C} ^{1\times L}$. Here we can see that $\alpha _{l}^{*}=\angle \beta _l
$ is the optimal solution, where $\beta _l$ is the $l$th element of $\boldsymbol{\beta }$.
In fact the optimization about $\bar{\mathbf{B}}$ is also an interesting question. Let's take a concrete example ($N=3$,$L=2$) here：\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\beta }^H\boldsymbol{\alpha }=\left[ \begin{matrix}
 x_1&  x_2&  x_3\\
\end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
 1&  0\\
 0&  1\\
 1&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 e^{j\alpha _1}\\
 e^{j\alpha _2}\\
\end{array} \right] =\left[ \begin{matrix}
 x_1+x_3&  x_2\\
\end{matrix} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 e^{j\alpha _1}\\
 e^{j\alpha _2}\\
\end{array} \right] 
\end{align}
where $x_n$ is the $n$th element of $\mathbf{x}$. The difficulty with this question is that $N>L$. When $N\leqslant L
$, the result that the original problem is optimal is necessarily $\sum_{n=1}^N{|x_n|}
$.
From another perspective, this optimization problem is equivalent to finding how to select and combine vectors from a finite set of vectors in complex space to achieve the optimal modulus.
I'm wondering if there's a way or an idea to get $\bar{\mathbf{B}}$.
